# Preventing non-human generated requests

Tags: php, web-applications, curl, captcha, capture

I developed a PHP application that its main use case is fetching some data from a database. I want prevent fetching all record of database data by using fake requests. The UI is simple (similar to Google home page) but I want to provide a link to previous and next records, no sign up is required to use the application.

What is your suggested solution?

*Update: *
By fake request I mean requests that are generated by non-human e.i. some mechanism like cURL, you generally prevent such requests via CAPTCHA.

Comment: What do you mean by fake requests? Requests that come from other sites, not your own?

Comment: Use LIMIT and mysql_real_escape_string() in your SQL query? I don't know, there are many possibilities to go wrong.

Comment: Just as @Emily daid, you first has to define what is a "real request" and what a "fake request". Does the user start a *real request* by pressing a button? is he logged?

Comment: @Emily The question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do, but beware: some users may dislike it.

- If users are expected to log in before they can do a search, then you must check if there is a valid logged in user (I know this is obvious and probably not your case, but may help to another reading your question).
- You can setup a request handler (I'm a ASP.Net guy) that doesn't allows more than 1 request from same IP every second, or 30 request every minute, etc...
- Just as @user1781026 said, your request should have LIMIT (mySql) or TOP (SQL Server), since usually the user is not going to need all your database records if they are more than 100 or 50000, just chose a "good" number for this limit.
- You may also require that the user select a "category" or a range of dates (kind of "this month", "last month", "this year"...).
- If you have to avoid "any" non-human request, then your only choices are (afaik) to require a log in or using a captcha.

Comment: How can I let only search engines to crab my data but no one else?

Comment: Wow, that is a whole new question: that depends on what kind of data you want the search engine to grab, also what you do to prevent the "fake requests" will probably prevent the search engine bots to grab the data too. You should make a new question, and add a link to this one so other users can know the context.