# How can I let only search engines to grab my data but no one else?

Tags: php, request, web-scraping, search-engine

I developed a PHP application, its main purpose is to fetch data from a database. I want to prevent fetching all records from database by using machine requests (I mean requests those are made by non-human i.e. some mechanism like CURL, you generally prevent such requests via CAPTCHA.).

How can I let only search engines to grab my data but no one else without sensible usability damage ?

related: [Preventing non-human generated requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13781182/752603)

Answer (score 0):

To open your question, I clicked the link and my browser made the request to the stackOverflow server and asked for this page. That's the same what cURL does... except it can't handle JavaScript. But again, I didn't parse the JavaScript on behalf of my browser. It was again, a program.

what I really needed to emphasis is that, virtually there is no way you can prevent a machine from faking a user activity.

But here are some tricks if you are interested. Personally I prefer methods that doesn't involve the human directly.

- Add a captcha challenge to pages.
- If your target audience is mostly modern people with modern browsers, use some Ajax page loading. This will keep most low end scrapers but not all. Google can process some ajax requests. See hashbangs.
- Add a captcha challenge to pages.
- If your target audience is mostly modern people with modern browsers, use some Ajax page loading. This will keep most low end scrapers but not all. Google can process some ajax requests. See hashbangs.
- Log IP addresses of the users and look for guys with several thousands of hits in a small time.
- Add some flood control to the site. You can disallow a form submission (for example) from being processing more than once in a minute.
- Add tokens to the form and validate it. This will at least make the crawling a two step process.
- And make your site fetch a little data from the database. For an example, if your application is a calendar, you can disallow all requests to show dates in a range longer than an year.

You can't block bots by its user agent. cURL and other programs can use a user-given different user agent when making the request.

You can adjust how googlebot should behave in Google web master central. Try to match it with your flood control mechanism. 
and remember, Google advices you not to depend on its user agent.